# Django and SQL Server - Error when charfield > 10 chars

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, windows-server-2008

I'm using Django 1.2.3 and django-pyodbc.

I am receiving an **error when adding a user with length > 10chars**:

> The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator

---

Whenever I add a user with username of 10 characters or below it works fine, same error for emails.

Any idea folks?

---

#### The user table:

```
CREATE TABLE [auth_user] (
    [id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [username] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [first_name] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [last_name] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [email] nvarchar(75) NOT NULL,
    [password] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    [is_staff] bit NOT NULL,
    [is_active] bit NOT NULL,
    [is_superuser] bit NOT NULL,
    [last_login] datetime NOT NULL,
    [date_joined] datetime NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with SQL Server 2008 and the SQL Native Client odbc driver. Upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 fixed the problem. It seemed to be  caused by an issue with the results from the SQLGetTypeInfo() odbc call for the WVARCHAR type including some date/time types too.

Comment: Thanks loads!!! I really hope this fixes it, I'm using SQL Server 2008 too, and I'm going to try and get it upgraded to R2. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `python manage.py sqlall <appname>` to see what the definition of `CREATE TABLE` for your table.

Comment: nope, I have added the output hoping you would have some insight :)

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, I fixed it by setting the TDS Version to 7.2:

```
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so',
        'host_is_server': True,
        'extra_params': 'TDS_Version=7.2',
    }
```

See the next link for a table of TDS Versions: [Choosing a TDS protocol version](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)